# What happens if a 302 URI can't be found?

Tags: http, lamp

If I make an HTTP request to get index.html on http://www.example.com but that URL has a 302 re-direct in place that points to http://www.foo.com/index.html, what happens if the redirect target (http://www.foo.com/index.html) isn't available? Will the user agent try the original URL (http://www.example.com/index.html) or just return an error?

Background to the question: I manage a legacy site that supports a few existing customers but doesn't allow new signs ups. Pretty much all the pages are redirected (using 302s rather than 301s for some unknown reason...) to a newer site. This includes the sign up page. On one of the pages that *isn't* redirected there is still a link to the sign up page which itself links through to a third party payment page (i.e. on another domain). Last week our current site went down for a couple of hours and in that period someone successfully signed up through the old site. The only way I can imagine this happened is that if a 302 doesn't find its intended URL some (all?) user agents bypass the redirect and then go to originally requested URL.

By the way, I'm aware there are many better ways to handle the particular situation we're in with the two sites. We're on it! This is just one of those weird situations I want to get to the bottom of.

Comment: Why would the user agent retry the first URL?

Comment: If a URI can't be found, it returns 404.

Comment: Looks like you made a configuration error. Your sign-up page should have been **replaced** with a 301. But it obviously still exists, else it would have been impossible to sign up.

Comment: @asjo - Well, I wouldn't have thought they would. I would expect the error message (404, 501 or whatever) that the redirect link points to to be returned. But in this case I don't think that happened. I just can't work out how someone accessed this page and the fact that it happened during a site outage makes me think the two are connected.

Comment: @msalters - yep, it should have been. The odd thing is I can't work out a single way to access that page on the public site and it doesn't even turn up in search. I don't know how this person found it!

Comment: It will not retry. retrying the first url will create a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should receive a `404 Not Found` status code.

Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, there is no real connection between two requests of a user agent. The redirection status codes are just a way for servers to politely tell their clients that the resource they were looking for is somewhere else now. The clients, however, are in no way obliged to actually request the resource from that other URL.

> Oh, the signup page is at *that* URL now? Well then I don't want it anymore... I'll go and look at some kittens instead.

Moreover, even if the client decides to do request the new URL (which it usually does ^^), this can be considered as a completely new communication between server and client. Neither server nor client should remember that there was a previous request which resulted in a redirection status code. Instead, the current request should be treated as if it was the first (and only) request. And what happens when you request a URL that cannot be found? You get a `404 Not Found` status code.